# Adding a delegate for calayer drawing crashes app

Tags: ios, crash, calayer

I wrote the following code in a file called PieChartView.m:

```
#pragma mark DrawingDelegate
@interface DrawingDelegate : NSObject
@end

@implementation DrawingDelegate

- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {
    //nothing here yet...
}

#pragma mark PieChartView
@implementation PieChartView

@synthesize pie_layer;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
            float pie_layer_width = 300.f;
            float pie_layer_height = 160.f;
            float pie_layer_PosX = 7.f;
            float pie_layer_PosY = 20.f;

            DrawingDelegate* layerDelegate = [[DrawingDelegate alloc] init];

            pie_layer = [[CALayer alloc] init];

            //when commenting the following assignment the app no longer crashes
            pie_layer.delegate = layerDelegate;
            pie_layer.bounds = CGRectMake( 0.f, 0.f, pie_layer_width, pie_layer_height );
            pie_layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
            pie_layer.position = CGPointMake( pie_layer_width/2+pie_layer_PosX, pie_layer_height/2+pie_layer_PosY );
            pie_layer.cornerRadius = 10.f;
            CGFloat components[4] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };

            CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
            CGColorRef black = CGColorCreate( colorspace, components );
            pie_layer.borderColor = black;
            pie_layer.borderWidth = 1.f;
            pie_layer.shadowRadius = 5.f;
            pie_layer.shadowColor = black;

            CGColorRelease( black );
            CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);

            pie_layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake( 0.f, 5.f ),
            pie_layer.shadowOpacity = 0.75f;
            [self.layer insertSublayer:pie_layer above:self.layer];
            [pie_layer setNeedsDisplay];
        }
        return self;
}
```

Strangly the app crashes as long as I execute the line "pie_layer.delegate = layerDelegate;". The crash looks like the given screenshot.

[image]

Why does this happen? What is wrong in my code?

Here is another more detailed stacktrace:
[image]

Comment: A couple of debugging tips: go to the Breakpoint Navigator and set a breakpoint on Objective-C exceptions, and move the slider at the bottom of the Debug Navigator to the right so that it show the whole stack.

Comment: Ah, I never noticed that slider at the bottom. Thanks for this tip. I added another screenshot with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is `ARC` and the delegate is `weak` then the drawing delegate will be released as nothing takes ownership of it.

Delegates by convention are weak but something needs to keep a `strong` reference to the DrawingDelegate object you create.

Comment: This is a good spot, but it would just mean the delegate was set to nil, wouldn't it?

Comment: the delegate doesnt set to nil. its like you set an assign property var an autoreleased object for old non-arc.

Answer (score 0):

This had me chasing crashes for the better part of a day.  Warren Burton's answer is the same one I found, and I solved it by assigning the helper class alloc/init to a strong property, so it sticks around for use as a delegate.

Otherwise the weak mylayer.delegate reference isn't enough to keep it from being freed up.

The crash from this one isn't obvious either, deep within window.makeKeyAndVisible.